# Control gets overlapped while using inside the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

When we use more than one ComboBox inside the FlowLayoutPanel and increase the FontSize after InitializeComponent() control gets overlapped.

Any solution to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Priyanga B

Answer (score 4):

You can first call [`SuspendLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the `FlowLayoutpanel`, then change font size of `ComboBox` controls, then call [`ResumeLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Font = new Font(x.Font.FontFamily, Font.Size + 5, Font.Style));
flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: Have you ever noticed to the check mark and the up arrow at left side of the answers? ;)